# Calculate weighted sum over all points in chart.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I have a line chart I made using chart.js. When I hover over a data point, I want to calculate the weighted sum at that point using the difference between the two points. For example, if I have point[0] = 5 with weight 2 and point[1] = 10 with weight 3 and point[2] with weight 4, upon hovering on point[2], I should see a calculation like:

```
point[0]*2 + (point[1]-point[0])*3 + (point[2]-point[1])*4
```

and so on for other points on the line. Any tips on how to do this? I'm not sure if I need to be using a loop, but when I'm using conditionals for multiple indexes it seems to work. This is not optimal though.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
 point[0]*2 + (point[1]-point[0])*3 + (point[2]-point[1])*4
```

is equal to

```
4* point[2]- (point[0]+ point[1])
```

so for a point i,
 you need to calculate  `(i+2)*point[i]` , minus the sum from point[0] to point[n-1]

And yes, you need a loop to calculate it.